# Flutter - UPI QR Code generator not working in phonepe app

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-plugin, upi

I have created a widget with QR Code in flutter where I have generated the QR by using the plugin `upi_payment_qrcode_generator` https://pub.dev/packages?q=upi_payment_qrcode_generator.

I can't able to scan the generated QR code in my **PhonePe App** if I configured my **phonePe UPI ID**. But If I am using the other Upi app like Gpay and paytm, it is working properly in all the combination.

Issue: PhonePe UPI ID configured to generate QR, but can't able to scan in PhonePe app itself. Getting message like **'Unable to verify QR Code/ Invalid QR'**

Below code is to configure UPI details:

```
UPIDetails upiDetails = UPIDetails(
      upiID: '73975XXXXX@ybl', //phonePe UPI ID.
      payeeName: 'Mr John',
      amount: 10.00,
      transactionNote: "Testing",
    );
```

Below is my Code to generate QR Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: UPIPaymentQRCode(
        upiDetails: upiDetails,
        size: AppSizeConstants.SIZE_170,
        upiQRErrorCorrectLevel: UPIQRErrorCorrectLevel.high,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can Pass the `UPi ID` in this way:

```
final upiDetailsWithoutAmount = UPIDetails(
    upiID: "8789271003@upi",
    payeeName: "Basant Jha",
    amount: 200
);
```

Comment: It was the plugin issue, now they have fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
PIDetails upiDetails = UPIDetails(
      upiID: '7996676699', //phonePe UPI ID.
      payeeName: 'MANOJ R',
      amount: ,
      transactionNote: "Testing",
    );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it